# Are peas a complete food and nutrition source for squabs?

Tags: health, diet, feeding, eating, birds

I've been mulling on this thought for a while, but as of last night, I have two three-week-old squabs to feed and I figure I probably need to find the answer. So far, I have been feeding them defrosted peas. Does this contain enough nutrients and minerals for squabs to live on, or do they really need chick feed or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, there are very few foods that are a source of complete nutrition. *Always* add some variety to diets, whether it's your own diet, or your Squab's.

As for the question itself, I'll refer you to a good nutritional site:

http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/vegetables-and-vegetable-products/2521/2

You can see by looking at the charts that although peas are a good source of a variety of nutrients, there are a few important ones that it's lacking (mainly Vitamins B, D, E, and a couple minerals). That would suggest that if this was all they had over the long term, they may become deficient in these nutrients, so I would definitely add more variety.

Note I'm completely ignorant of the nutritional requirements for Squabs. This is just to outline the weaknesses of feeding them only peas.